# Disable strike trough comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

In vscode when commenting a block that already contains other comments will display the inner comments as strike-trough lines, also grayed out.

I'm not sure if this was an option or a plugin I've installed or a native behavior, but I couldn't find a way to disable this behavior.

Example

```
/* function helloFn() {
  // this is a comment within my function
  return "Hello"
} */
```

[image]

The inner comment will be displayed as <del>// this is a comment within my function</del>.

This is true wether I use an outer comment block or a line by line comment.
As soon there is a comment within a comment it will trigger this behavior.

**Q: How to disable this?**

Comment: Try the command `Help: Start Extension Bisect` to see if it is one of your installed extensions.  I think it is.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: I've solved it using `Help: Start Extension Bisect`, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark's comment I've used `Help: Start Extension Bisect` and found out it was caused by the [Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) extension.

In particular this part of the settings:

```
  {
    "tag": "//",
    "color": "#474747",
    "strikethrough": true,
    "underline": false,
    "backgroundColor": "transparent",
    "bold": false,
    "italic": false
  },
```

By changing `"strikethrough": false` solved the problem